# How do I query for objects created before a certain hour in a day in Django?

Tags: python, django

In Django, I am trying to filter my query only to objects that were created before a certain hour in the day. I have a datetime field called 'created_at' that stored the datetime from which that object was created.

What I would like to do is:

```
query = query.filter(created_at__hour__lte=10)
```

Which I would expect to get all the objects that were created before 10am. However, when I try that I get a:

```
FieldError: Join on field 'created_at' not permitted. Did you misspell 'hour' for the lookup type?
```

I could loop through each day and get that day's objects, but that seems highly inefficient. Is there a way I can do this in a single query? If not, what is the fastest way to run this sort of filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__hour` on a `DateTimeField` is a lookup type, so you can't mix it with another lookup type like `__lte`. You could construct a filter with `Q` objects, EG:

```
before_ten = Q(created_at__hour=0)
for hour in range(1, 11):
    before_ten = before_ten | Q(created_at__hour=hour)
query = query.filter(before_ten)
```

If you can change your data model, it might be more convenient to save a creation time `TimeField` as well as your existing `created_at`.

Comment: The reason I was hesitant to use for loops is because I'm running through up to a million entries and speed is an issue. I will try this solution and see how long it takes.
Do you know if Q hits the database 10 times? Or does it mash up into one big query?

Comment: If you use this approach, you can generate the `before_ten` filter before your loop and then apply it each time. Django's ORM is smart enough that it will mash it down into one query.

Comment: `Q` objects mash it up into one big query. It basically expresses "hour == 0 or hour == 1 or hour == 2..."

Answer (score 2):

In Django 1.9+, you can chain hour lookups like `created_at__hour__lte`, so the query from the question *will* work.

```
query = query.filter(created_at__hour__lte=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
start_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=00, minute=00)
certain_hour = 10
end_time = start_time.replace(hour=certain_hour)

query = query.filter(created_at__range=(start_time, end_time)
```

Comment: Your answer takes into consideration the current day, but I'm asking for since morning for every day.